# AlarmManager interval changes when other application is running

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intervals, android-alarms

I'm working on an app which sets a repeating alarm.

It's supposed to run one of my services every 2 min for example.
When myApplication activity is running it works fine, but when other app is running in foreground the interval goes to 5 min!!!

I run this code inside another service which is starting in foreground.

I don't know why this is happening.

```
public class Serv1 extends Service{

 public static Intent intentServ2 = new Intent(G.context,Serv2.class);
public static   PendingIntent pendingIntend=PendingIntent.getService(G.context,0,intentServ2,0);
public  static AlarmManager alarmManager;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 alarmManager =(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+(2*1000),120*1000,pendingIntend);


  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Serv1.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Serive1")
            .setContentText("Service is working...")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();


    startForeground(254698, notification);





    return Service.START_STICKY;

}
```

Comment: What android version are you running on?

Comment: lollipop  api 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [AlarmManager docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

You might be experiencing those inexact alarms.

Also note that if you want the device to wake up when the alarm goes off, you need [RTC_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP).